# Transaction (Process ID 120) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, deadlock

In our organization there is an old desktop application built in c# which connects sql server db.
It is running since 2008.
Now suddenly it is giving an error

```
Transaction (Process ID) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction
```

this can be solved in code level, which I got from other similar posts. The problem here is I dont have source code of the application but I have access to DB. Can this be solved on Db level. Any settings in SQl Server 2005 which can prevent this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes this can be solved at DB level.First you need to enable some trace flags to capture this when this occurs again..

Enabling below trace flags make SQL server write deadlocks information to Errorlog

```
DBCC TRACEON (1204, -1)
DBCC TRACEON (1222, -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as "settings", that may be difficult if you don't have access to the code to see and/or re-write the code. There is no magic button to make deadlocks go away, or prevent them, there are things to try to alleviate them. I would find out the exact pieces of code that are causing the deadlock issues. Along with what TheGameiswar mentions above, if you know a small timeframe of when this happens then you can also run Profiler. Once you've identified the objects that are causing deadlocks, look closer at the tables and stored procedures being executed and try to make any improvements (indexes and stats and etc...). There are also some other utilities to run that may help; sp_Blitz, sp_BlitzIndex, sp_BlitzCache, and sp_WhoIsActive are things that I use frequently for performance and deadlocking/blocking issues.